# Execute a command-line Application via ShellExecute() and get its return value

Tags: delphi, winapi, pipe, createprocess, shellexecute

I am a Delphi developer in our company. We need a function which launches a command-line executable and get its return value.

The code I wrote, and all the examples I found on the Internet, do this via `CreateProcess()`, but my boss rejected this and told me that there MUST be a solution doing this via `ShellExecute()`. I can't find any example on the Internet doing this with `ShellExecute()`. All of them use `CreateProcess()`.

Below are 3 methods I delivered to my boss. He did not like `ShellExecute_AndGetReturnValue()`. It's named "ShellExecute", but it does not use `ShellExecute()`.

All of these 3 methods are working fine. But the first one is not using `ShellExecute()`. Instead it is using `CreateProcess()`.

So, is it possible to solve/change the `ShellExecute_AndGetReturnValue()` method so that it will use `ShellExecute()` instead of `CreateProcess()`? All examples I found, all of them, use `CreateProcess()`.

```
function ShellExecute_AndGetReturnValue(FileName : string; Params : string = ''; Show : Integer = SW_HIDE; WorkingDir : string = '') : string;
const
  READ_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
var
  Security: TSecurityAttributes;
  readableEndOfPipe, writeableEndOfPipe, readableErrorEndOfPipe, writeableErrorEndOfPipe: THandle;
  start: TStartUpInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
  Buffer: PAnsiChar;
  BytesRead: DWORD;
  AppRunning: DWORD;
  ResultStdOutput : string;
  ResultErrOutput : string;
  lpDirectory : PAnsiChar;
  CmdLine : string;
begin
  Result := '';
  Security.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
  Security.bInheritHandle := True;
  Security.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;

  if CreatePipe(readableEndOfPipe, writeableEndOfPipe, @Security, 0) then
  begin
    Buffer := AllocMem(READ_BUFFER_SIZE + 1);
    FillChar(Start, Sizeof(Start), #0);
    FillChar(ProcessInfo, SizeOf(ProcessInfo), #0);

    start.cb := SizeOf(start);
    start.dwFlags := start.dwFlags or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    start.hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    start.hStdOutput := writeableEndOfPipe;

    CreatePipe(readableErrorEndOfPipe, writeableErrorEndOfPipe, @Security, 0);
    start.hStdError := writeableErrorEndOfPipe;
    start.hStdError := writeableEndOfPipe;
    start.dwFlags := start.dwFlags + STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    start.wShowWindow := Show;

    UniqueString(FileName);
    CmdLine := '"' + FileName + '" ' + Params;

    if WorkingDir <> '' then
    begin
      lpDirectory := PAnsiChar(WorkingDir);
    end else
    begin
      lpDirectory := PAnsiChar(ExtractFilePath(FileName));
    end;

    if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CmdLine), nil, nil, True, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, lpDirectory, start, ProcessInfo) then
    begin
      repeat
          Apprunning := WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 100);
          Application.ProcessMessages;
      until (Apprunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);

      ResultStdOutput := '';
      ResultErrOutput := '';

      //Must Close write Handles before reading (if the console application does not output anything)
      CloseHandle(writeableEndOfPipe);
      CloseHandle(writeableErrorEndOfPipe);

      repeat
        BytesRead := 0;
        ReadFile(readableEndOfPipe, Buffer[0], READ_BUFFER_SIZE, BytesRead, nil);
        Buffer[BytesRead]:= #0;
        OemToAnsi(Buffer,Buffer);
        ResultStdOutput := ResultStdOutput + String(Buffer);
      until (BytesRead < READ_BUFFER_SIZE);

      if start.hStdOutput <> start.hStdError then
      begin
        BytesRead := 0;
        ReadFile(readableErrorEndOfPipe, Buffer[0], READ_BUFFER_SIZE, BytesRead, nil);
        Buffer[BytesRead]:= #0;
        OemToAnsi(Buffer,Buffer);
        ResultErrOutput := ResultErrOutput + String(Buffer);
      end;
    end;

    Result := ResultStdOutput;

    FreeMem(Buffer);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(readableEndOfPipe);
    CloseHandle(readableErrorEndOfPipe);
  end;
end;

procedure ShellExecute_NoWait(FileName : string; Params : string = ''; Action : string = 'open'; Show : Integer = SW_SHOWNORMAL; WorkingDir : string = '');
var
  exInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  Ph: DWORD;
begin
  FillChar(exInfo, SizeOf(exInfo), 0);
  with exInfo do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(exInfo);
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT;
    Wnd := GetActiveWindow();
    lpVerb := PAnsiChar(Action);
    lpParameters := PChar(Params);
    lpFile := PChar(FileName);
    nShow := Show;
    if WorkingDir <> '' then
    begin
      lpDirectory := PAnsiChar(WorkingDir);
    end else
    begin
      lpDirectory := PAnsiChar(ExtractFilePath(FileName));
    end;
  end;
  if ShellExecuteEx(@exInfo) then
  begin
    Ph := exInfo.HProcess;
    CloseHandle(Ph);
  end;
end;

procedure ShellExecute_AndWait(FileName : string; Params : string = ''; Action : string = 'open'; Show : Integer = SW_SHOWNORMAL; WorkingDir : string = '');
var
  exInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  Ph: DWORD;
begin
  FillChar(exInfo, SizeOf(exInfo), 0);
  with exInfo do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(exInfo);
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT;
    Wnd := GetActiveWindow();
    lpVerb := PAnsiChar(Action);
    lpParameters := PChar(Params);
    lpFile := PChar(FileName);
    nShow := Show;
    if WorkingDir <> '' then
    begin
      lpDirectory := PAnsiChar(WorkingDir);
    end else
    begin
      lpDirectory := PAnsiChar(ExtractFilePath(FileName));
    end;
  end;
  if ShellExecuteEx(@exInfo) then
  begin
    Ph := exInfo.HProcess;
    while WaitForSingleObject(ExInfo.hProcess, 50) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 do
    begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
    CloseHandle(Ph);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: ShellExecuteEx can delegate execution to Shell extensions (data sources, context menu handlers, verb implementations) that are activated using Component Object Model (COM).  If your not using any of that there is not much point to restricting yourself to using it.

Comment: WHY is your boss so adament on using `ShellExecute()`? What does he think it can do that can't be done any other way? Without that info, it is difficult to give you a viable replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Task from your boss is not fully correct. Problem is that the generic solution of ShellExecute – is not start cmd.exe, this command starts an application that is linked to this type of file and starts it. So, to make it work like you want – it needs a lot of work.
One more thing – do you need to get the result of work of your program or console output of your program?
Here is modified part of sources from jcl library to return return code:

```
function PCharOrNil(const S: string): PChar;
begin
  Result := Pointer(S);
end;

// memory initialization
procedure ResetMemory(out P; Size: Longint);
begin
  if Size > 0 then
  begin
    Byte(P) := 0;
    FillChar(P, Size, 0);
  end;
end;

function ShellExecAndWait(const FileName: string; const Parameters: string;
  const Verb: string; CmdShow: Integer; const Directory: string): cardinal;
var
  Sei: TShellExecuteInfo;
  Res: LongBool;
  Msg: tagMSG;
  ShellResult : boolean;
begin
  ResetMemory(Sei, SizeOf(Sei));
  Sei.cbSize := SizeOf(Sei);
  Sei.fMask := SEE_MASK_DOENVSUBST  or SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI  or SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS or
    SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT or SEE_MASK_NOASYNC;
  Sei.lpFile := PChar(FileName);
  Sei.lpParameters := PCharOrNil(Parameters);
  Sei.lpVerb := PCharOrNil(Verb);
  Sei.nShow := CmdShow;
  Sei.lpDirectory := PCharOrNil(Directory);
  {$TYPEDADDRESS ON}
  ShellResult := ShellExecuteEx(@Sei);
  {$IFNDEF TYPEDADDRESS_ON}
  {$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
  {$ENDIF ~TYPEDADDRESS_ON}
  if ShellResult then begin
    WaitForInputIdle(Sei.hProcess, INFINITE);

    while WaitForSingleObject(Sei.hProcess, 10) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
      repeat
        Msg.hwnd := 0;
        Res := PeekMessage(Msg, Sei.Wnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
        if Res then
        begin
          TranslateMessage(Msg);
          DispatchMessage(Msg);
        end;
      until not Res;

    if not GetExitCodeProcess(Sei.hProcess, Result) then
      raise Exception.Create('GetExitCodeProcess fail');

    CloseHandle(Sei.hProcess);
  end else begin
    raise Exception.Create('ShellExecuteEx fail');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  xResult : cardinal;
begin
  xResult := ShellExecAndWait('ping.exe', '', '', 1, '');  //xResult = 1
  xResult := ShellExecAndWait('ping.exe', '8.8.8.8', '', 1, '');  //xResult = 0
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to specify input/output pipes (to control stdin and stdout of the called process) then ShellExecute cannot be used. It simply does not support specifying these. Neither does ShellExecuteEx.

So the only option you have if you *must* use ShellExecute is to ShellExecute the command processor (CMD.EXE) and ask *it* to perform the redirection of input and output. This will limit your redirection source and target to physical files on the disk, as that's the way CMD.EXE allows redirection (>StdOut <StdIn).

Othwewise, your approach with CreateProcess is the way forward. What does your boss give as reason that you *must* use ShellExecute?

If you *don't* need redirection support, you can use ShellExecuteEx and then after a successful execution, you can obtain the Handle to the running process in Info.hProcess (Info is the TShellExecuteInfo structure passed to ShellExecuteEx).

This value can then be used in GetExitCodeProcess to determine if the process is still running, or if it has terminated (and you have thus retrieved the "Return Value", if I have correctly understood your use of this expression - it's actually called an "ExitCode", or - in batch files - an "ERRORLEVEL").

Incomplete code:

```
FUNCTION ShellExecuteAndWait(....) : DWORD;
.
.
VAR Info : TShellExecuteInfo;
.
.
Info.fMask:=Info.fMask OR SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
IF NOT ShellExecuteEx(Info) THEN EXIT($FFFF8000);
IF Info.hProcess=0 THEN EXIT($FFFF0000);
REPEAT
  IF NOT GetExitCodeProcess(Info.hProcess,Result) THEN EXIT($FFFFFFFF)
UNTIL Result<>STILL_ACTIVE
.
.
```

The above code should demonstrate how to do this...

Comment: thank you for your answer. that confirms my result, that it is NOT possible with ShellExecute. All we want is to run a console application from a delphi winform application, wait until it has exited, and after that get the return of the output. my first method does exactly this, but it is using createprocess, not shellexecute. that is why my boss claims i should not use createprocess and go with shellexecute instead, but all my researches say me, i can not go with shellexecute if i want to capture and return the output, that is why i delivered a solution to him with createprocess instead.

Comment: @Karkadam: You _can_ achieve this by executing the file via CMD.EXE. Execute _GetEnvironment('COMSPEC')+' /C '+QuotedFileName(ExeFile)+' >'+QuotedFileName(TmpFile)_ and then read TmpFile afterwards. This, however, requires that you know the .EXE file to be run, and do not rely on _ShellExecute_'s ability to "run", f.ex., a TXT file.

Comment: Using `ShellExecute/Ex()` (or `CreateProcess()`), if you have a handle to the spawned process then rather than using a `repeat` loop on `GetExitCodeProcess()`, you should instead use `WaitForSingleObject()` (or equivalent) to wait for the process handle to be signaled on termination, and then call `GetExitCodeProcess()` one time to get the final exit code.